# problems executing a jquery ajax call within a function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have following code for Jquery Cange Event

```
$("input[name=evnt_typ]").change(function(){
    var request = $.ajax({
                            method: "POST",
                            url: "ajaxRequest.php",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: {fn: 'getCompanyMaster'},
                        });

                        request.done(function (reqResult){

                            $('.dynmic_cotnt').html('');
                            $('.panel-footer').hide();

                            var append_string = '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">'+
                            '<div class="row form-group">'+
                                '<label class="control-label col-lg-3">Select'+ ' Company</label><span class="col-lg-1 hidden-xs">:</span>'+
                                '<div class="col-lg-8">'+ 
                                    '<select class="chosen" name="company_master" style="width:400px;" onChange="getCompanyEvent(this)">'+
                                        '<option>Select</option>';
                                    $.each(reqResult.result, function(ind, va){
                                        append_string += '<option value='+va.refid+'>'+va.company_name+' ('+va.industry+')</option>';
                                    });
                                    append_string +=  '</select>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+ 
                            '</div>';
                            //alert(append_string);
                            $('#dynmic_slct').html(append_string); 
                            jQuery(".chosen").chosen();
                        });
                        request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus){
                            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                        });
});
```

in Above Code i have to create Dynamic Select Element and call `getCompanyEvent()` in Change event..

```
function getCompanyEvent(element){

            var selected_cid = element.value;

                alert(selected_cid);

                var request = $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "ajaxRequest.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {fn: 'getCompanyEvent', company_id: selected_cid},
                    success: function(reqResult){
                        var append_string = '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">'+
                                '<div class="row form-group">'+
                                    '<label class="control-label col-lg-3">Select'+ ' Event</label><span class="col-lg-1">:</span>'+
                                    '<div class="col-lg-8">'+ 
                                        '<select class="chosen" style="width:200px;" onChange="getTemp(this)>'+
                                          '<option>Select</option>';
                                        $.each(reqResult.result, function(ind, va){
                                            append_string += '<option value='+va.event_id+'>'+va.event_name+'</option>';
                                        });    
                    append_string += '</select>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</div>'+ 
                            '</div>';
                        $('#dynmic_slct').append(append_string);
                        jQuery(".chosen").chosen();
                    }
                }); 
        }
```

above functions and Change event i have wrote Same document (index.php)..
acutully the above fn generate dynamic select element with lable **select Event** but i got label only see result [image]

i have also checked my php logic every thing is good that's return result set..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very silly mistake and very hard to debug.

If you see your code this line

```
'<select class="chosen" style="width:200px;" onChange="getTemp(this)>'+
```

needs to this

```
'<select class="chosen" style="width:200px;" onChange="getTemp(this)">'+
```

Added `"` after `getTemp(this)`

```js
var reqResult = {};
reqResult.result = [{
  event_id: '1',
  event_name: 'er'
}, {
  event_id: '2',
  event_name: 'erewr ewrewr'
}, {
  event_id: '3',
  event_name: 'erewr'
}, ]

var success = function(reqResult) {
  var append_string = '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">' +
    '<div class="row form-group">' +
    '<label class="control-label col-lg-3">Select' + ' Event</label><span class="col-lg-1">:</span>' +
    '<div class="col-lg-8">' +
    '<select class="chosen" style="width:200px;" onChange="getTemp(this)>"' +
    '<option>Select</option>';
  $.each(reqResult.result, function(ind, va) {
    append_string += '<option value=' + va.event_id + '>' + va.event_name + '</option>';
  });
  append_string += '</select></div></div></div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';
  $('#dynmic_slct').append(append_string);
}
success(reqResult)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dynmic_slct"></div>
```